# composition of a number using 1 and 2

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of partitions of $n$ in which all parts are $1$ or $2$ is
$$
\Bigl\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \Bigr\rfloor
$$

Similarly how can I formulate the number of compositions formed using $1$ or $2$?

I could come up with a following series:
If $n = 7$, then the number of compositions using $1$ and $2$ is
$$
\binom{7}{0} + \binom{6}{1} + \binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{3} = 21.
$$

How can I form a formula to calculate the sum of this series?

Definitions: [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F(n)$ be the number of compositions of $n$ by $1$ and $2$.  A composition of $n$ can either end in $1$ or $2$.  There are $F(n-1)$ that end in $1$ and $F(n-2)$ that end in $2$, so we have $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$.  Does that look familiar?

Comment: fibonacci series right ? And the fastest way to calculate the sum would be fibonacci exponentiation.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @g4ur4v:  Exactly right.  You need to think a bit about how this $n$ matches up with the indices of the Fibonacci series.